# key card battery message still on megane 59 after replacing battery

Tags: electrical

I have a Renault Megane 59 plate and have just replaced the key card battery after a message came up on the dash, but the message still hasn't gone.Can anyone tell me how to get that message off? Thanks

Comment: "What is a 59 plate?"  It's a 2009: http://www.theaa.com/car-buying/number-plates

Comment: How many times have you started and stopped the car since you replaced the battery?  It might take a few trips.